# Evolution of Quantum Harmonic Oscillator into coherent state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, time-evolution, coherent-states

Why does a quantum harmonic oscillator that is driven by an electromagnetic wave in cosine form with its frequency equal to the resonance frequency of the oscillator evolve from its groundstate into a coherent state?

The Hamiltonian of the harmonic oscillator is $\hat{H} = \hat{Q}^2 /2C + \hat{\phi}^2 /2L $, where $\hat{Q}$ is the charge operator and $\hat{\phi}$ the flux operator. If you then influence it by a driving field with the Hamiltonian $\hat{H} = \hat{Q}\, V_0\, \cos(\omega_0t) $, where $\omega_0$ is the resonance frequency of the harmonic oscillator, the oscillator will apparently evolve from the groundstate into a coherent state. I don't understand, why this happening.

I know, that the coherent state is a state where the expectation values of the oscillator are equal to the classic behavior.

Comment: You should add some equations and context (e.g. sources). Further, you should show your work, i.e. what you have tried so far.

Comment: Like that? Or do you need more information?

Comment: Do you have any reference for that? And what have you tried to prove this statement? Include some computations and explain what exactly you don't understand. BTW: Do you mean, by chance, $Q^2$ and $\phi^2$ in $H$? Perhaps it is just me, but it seems that the notation is really non-standard, at least compared to the ordinary discussion of the QHO in undergraduate QM... Again: Do you follow any particular book, perhaps of a certain subject?

Comment: No, I follow a lecture about superconducting circuits for Quantum computing and there the josephson-junctions are driven by an electromagnetic field. To derive this, we first assumed a harmonic oscillator of an LC-resonator and applied a field to that, and apparently this will then evolve into a coherent state. Here is a paper about this topic:  https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.76.042319